# how to implement "istyping" for a messenger app in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

How can I implement the "isTyping" in my iOS messenger app?

### My idea:

Consider we have 2 users.
when user1 starts typing the client app tells this to the server.
A silent push notification is sent to user2
This notification makes user2 know that user1 is typing.
When user1 stops typing it tells to the server and another silent push notification is sent to make user2 know about this change.

### Problems and questions about this idea

- silent push notifications have low priority
- Is it a good idea to send several push notifications to do this
- When I disabled push notification from Telegram iOS app it kept alerting about "isTypping", so is there a better way to do this?

Comment: you can use "SocketIO" for this.

Comment: you can use sendbird, quickblox SDK for this.

Comment: You can use Firebase, as its easy to implement and no push notifications required.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Firebase` to store only the istyping information between users.
Since `Firebase` allows you to observe properties in real time, you can change your views whenever the value of this property changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can have one DateTime field in your user table. Let say lastTypedCharacter and store DateTime and update it every second when user A is typing anything. When showing to the other user B match the lastTypedCharacter DateTime with the current time if its less than 5 seconds then you can assume that the user A is no longer typing